# Stripe - Card token and confirming card holder billing address

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

When using `stripe.tokens.create`, there are optional fields such as `address_state`.

In **test mode** I've put in random letters into this field, such as:

```
number: 4242424242424242
cvc: 123,
address_state: 'lalala'
```

And when I do this, Stripe still accepts this as valid. I'm wondering if this is because I'm in **test mode** that Stripe accepts anything in the `address_state` field, or does Stripe behave the same way when using it via **live mode**?

Basically, does Stripe validate Address fields or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a card token client-side, Stripe does not validate the card number with the bank yet. Instead they simply verify that the values are coherent (card not expired, CVC with the correct number of digits, etc.) and create a token successfully. Stripe doesn't do any validation on the billing address. The bank informs them of the check when the token is charged or when the card is saved on a customer.

When you charge the card, the issuing bank (read: your customer's bank) has the *choice* to decline your card based on what you input. Sometimes they'll approve the charge even if `cvc_check` and/or`address_zip_check` fails. You can configure Stripe to decline it anyway. The [Stripe defaults](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules#traditional-bank-checks) decline charges if `cvc_check` fails, but permits `address_zip_check` and `address_line1_check` failures. You can optionally make `address_zip_check` trigger a failure in [your dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/radar/rules).

You can experiment with these rules, by using some of [Stripe's test credit cards/tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards). For example, card `4000000000000036` (or token `tok_avsZipFail`) will *always* fail the `address_zip_check`.